# How can I assign multiple values to a hash key?

Tags: ruby, hash

For the sake of convenience I am trying to assign multiple values to a hash key in Ruby. Here's the code so far

```
myhash = { :name => ["Tom" , "Dick" , "Harry"] }
```

Looping through the hash gives a concatenated string of the 3 values

Output:

```
name : TomDickHarry
```

Required Output:

```
:name => "Tom" , :name => "Dick" , :name => "Harry"
```

What code must I write to get the required output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've created a hash with the symbol name as the key and an array with three elements as the value, so you'll need to iterate through `myhash[:name]` to get the individual array elements.

Answer (score 6):

```
myhash.each_pair {|k,v| v.each {|n| puts "#{k} => #{n}"}}
#name => Tom
#name => Dick
#name => Harry
```

The output format is not exactly what you need, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: @pierr, thank you. I have more than 1 keys in that hash and want to iterate over selective keys, for that I am trying
 Hash[*myhash.select {|k,v| [:name].include?(k)}.flatten] , but getting an error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The reason for the error is that flatten is recursive so you end up with 1 long list and not a list of pairs of keys and values.

Answer (score 5):

The answers from Rohith and pierr are fine in this case. However, if this is something you're going to make extensive use of it's worth knowing that the data structure which behaves like a Hash but allows multiple values for a key is usually referred to as a multimap. There are a couple of implementations of this for Ruby including [this one](http://github.com/josh/multimap).

Answer (score 3):

re: the issue of iterating over selective keys. Try using `reject` with the condition inverted instead of using `select`.

e.g. given:

```
{:name=>["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"], :keep=>[4, 5, 6], :discard=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

where we want `:name` and `:keep` but not `:discard`

with `select`:

```
myhash.select { |k, v| [:name, :keep].include?(k) }
=> [[:name, ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]], [:keep, [4, 5, 6]]]
```

The result is a list of pairs.

but with `reject`:

```
myhash.reject { |k, v| ![:name, :keep].include?(k) }
=> {:name=>["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"], :keep=>[4, 5, 6]}
```

The result is a Hash with only the entries you want.

This can then be combined with pierr's answer:

```
hash_to_use = myhash.reject { |k, v| ![:name, :keep].include?(k) }
hash_to_use.each_pair {|k,v| v.each {|n| puts "#{k} => #{n}"}}
```